# Авторизация ВКонтакте без использования Indy

Tags: delphi, вконтакте

Собственно в этом и вопрос, пробовал синапсом, но что-то не выходит, мб кто может поделиться рабочим скриптом?

PS: прошу в гугл/яндекс или тп меня не посылать

Comment: Чем не устраивает Indy?

Что именно не получается?

Смотрели что отправляет браузер и что отправляете Ваша программа?

в гугле и яндексе куча готовых(рабочих) примеров

Comment: @SoftR, ваше сообщение не содержит ответа.

Comment: в инди не устраивают кривые модули, постоянно проблемы с IdGlobal.pas

синапсом пробовал отсылать запросы, но почему-то до сервера доходила неполная строка

>'act=login&q=1&al_frame=1&expire=&captcha_sid=&captcha_key=&from_host=vkontakte.ru&email=v' 

а полностью строка выглядит так:

>'act=login&q=1&al_frame=1&expire=&captcha_sid=&captcha_key=&from_host=vkontakte.ru&email=' +edit1.Text+ '&pass=' +edit2.Text

вот и не могу разобраться...

Comment: PS: что самое непонятное: пробовал сделать кликер, который будет сам вводить логин и пароль в поля, но кликер пишет только логин и не спускается на пароль(хотя пробовал на других сайтах - кликер отлично справляется)

Comment: mail=**v**'

В Вашей строке откуда взялось?

Насчет кривости Indy это спорный вопрос, тем более если задача состоит в работе с vkontakte.ru , то Indy хватает за глаза, знаю по собственному опыту реализовано более десятка проектов по работе с контактом и все с использованием indy

Comment: email=понятно чему, логину, который начинается с v, но запрос отправляется обрезанный, непонятно почему. пытался вместо edit1.Text и edit2.Text вписать свои логин и пароль, но тут такая же история

+ заметил, пост-дата посылается пустая
и в ответ получаю 400 bad request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для авторизации практически на любом сайте можно использовать метод перебора HTML кода. Сначала лучше посмотреть исходный код страницы, если он большой, то этот метод может слишком долго работать, но есть выход: нарочно пишем неправильный пароль, затем браузер нас перекинет на другую страницу, там HTML код будет меньше, поэтому именно на ней будем авторизовываться программно. Создаём проект и кидаем на форму две кнопки и компонент WebBrowser с закладки Internet; первая кнопка нужна для открытия страницы, а вторая - для авторизации.

Код

```
// для кнопки открыть сайт
procedure TAutorizationForm.BitBtnOpenPageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
WebBrowser.Navigate('сюда пишем нужный сайт');
end;
// Для кнопки авторизация
procedure TAutorizationForm.BitBtnAutorizationClick(Sender: TObject);
Var
  i:Integer;
  s:String;
  html_tag:Variant;
begin
  html_tag:=WebBrowser.OleObject.Document.Forms.Item(0).Elements;
  For i:=0 To (html_tag.Length-1) Do
    Begin
      If (html_tag.item(i).name='здесь нужно написать имя поля, в которое требуется ввести имя пользователя') Then html_tag.item(i).value:='здесь пишем имя пользователя';
      If (html_tag.item(i).name='здесь нужно написать имя поля, в которое требуется ввести пароль') Then
        html_tag.item(i).value:='сюда записываем пароль';
      If (html_tag.item(i).value='сюда пишем имя кнопки для входа') Then html_tag.item(i).click;
    End;
end;
```

Comment: спасибо, логин и пароль Ваш код вводит, вот только проблема возникла с кнопкой, имени у нее нет:
><button id="quick_login_button">Войти</button>

вписал этот id в код, но ничего не произошло.
есть что посоветовать?

Comment: Насчёт имени кнопки я немножко приврал: там не имя а свойство value использовать надо. Этот код работает, если кнопка образована тегом <input>. Там ВКонтакте на сайте http://vkontakte.ru/login.php там ссылкой кнопка сделана. Тогда, может это так код поменять:
<pre>
If (html_tag.item(i).id='quick_login_button') Then html_tag.item(i).click;
</pre>
Я, если честно не знаю как, я только на одном сайте всегда авторизовываюсь и там работает, у меня была мысль усложнить прогу для авторизации на нескольких сайтах, но пока некогда.

Comment: тоже пробовал, только на vkontakte.ru/login.php
эта кнопка даже id не имеет
> a href="javascript: quick_login()">Вход</a>

вот запара...

Comment: Там код генерируеться динамически и все ваши потуги с TwebBrouser ни кчему не приведут

Answer (score 2):

Я считаю изварщением использовать Twebbrouser для работы с интернетом.
Есть множество компонентов для отправки PostGet запросов из Delphi
от WinSocks и не любимого автором темы Indy  до ICS Synapse и даже есть готовые компоненты для авторизациии на разных сайтах в том числе  и для сайта вконтакте.

Если Вы все таки отойдете от убеждения что Indy не подходит  я положу Вам кусочек кода для авторизации на сайте vkontakte.

Comment: Соглашусь. Это как если бы кто-то для перегонки видео в другой формат открывал его в WMP, захватывал картинку с экрана, обрезал лишнее и сохранял в нужный формат.

Comment: да я бы не против Indy, вот только компилятор ругается на IdGlobal.pas
не могу разобраться, поэтому и ищу другие методы...
а ошибка такова:
>[DCC Fatal Error] IdGlobal.pas(309): F2051 Unit IdStack was compiled with a different version of IdGlobal.TIdPort

буду признателен, если поможете разобраться с проблемой.

PS: SoftR, буду рад вашему кусочку кода

Comment: Для начала поставьте последнюю официальную версию Indy соответствующей для вашей версии Delphi
Потому что у Вас даже в самой ошибке написано не соответствие версий.

**compiled  with a different version**

Comment: Ошибка повествует о том, что модуль IdStack был скомпилирован с другой версией класса dGlobal.TIdPort (более старой или более новой , чем у вас). Как правило, это значит, что у вас в путях поиска болтаются две разные версии компонента, или компонент криво установился в систему. Обычно помогает аккуратная и полная переустановка компонента (не забудьте проверить все пути).

Comment: Как оказалось, в пакете RAD Studio 2010 + Delphi 2010 Architect, от компонентов Indy только откомпилированные файлы(.dcu). Решил пере установить Инди, но столкнулся с проблемой: Indy можно скачать только с использованием TortoiseSVN, который на моей windows 7 не запускается никак... Хорошо, у меня есть второй комп, как раз с windows XP, там то я и скачал полный пакет Indy.
Переустановил - все заработало. Осталось придумать, для чего использовать программную авторизацию ВКонтакте.

всем спасибо за советы :)

Comment: Контакт в этом плане умер.
Если еще год назад один за одним заказы по прикладному софту для работы с Контактом, то сейчас контакт даром никому не нужен :)
сильно развитая паранойа у Дурова оборвала бизнес многим SMO-шникам, и как следствие прикладным программистам.
Я для контакта более 20 программ написал, и сейчас заказчики ими не пользуются, они ушли в другие социалки.